Error Xcode: Build input file cannot be found GoogleService-Info.plist. Did you forget to declare this file?
I faced with the Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '../ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? in my Flutter project.
I have two flavors (prod and dev) for my app. So, I created two GoogleService-Info.plist files for prod and dev.
I would like to have a folder named config in /ios folder. And in the config folder I want to make two folders: dev and prod where will I put these two files. How can I do this correctly?

you can do this way.

Create 2 folders inside Runner folder from the Finder or file Explorer.
Now open that project in Xcode and from xcode right click on runner and select "Add files to Runner"
It will open file explorer, from your project select ios/Runner and then select both 2 folders ( dev and prod ) and add it. you can tick copy resource upon asked.
No again goto dev and prod folder and add  GoogleService-Info.plist to both folder  based on dev and prod.
Now open that project in Xcode and from xcode right click on runner and select "Add files to Runner"
It will open file explorer, from your project select ios/Runner/dev/ and then select file and add it. you can tick copy resource upon asked. Same for prod as well.
Now to just make sure. Select target. Goto build phases in xcode. Find for Copy Bundle Resources and see there wheather its showing correct GoogleService-Info.plist file or not.

